# R's corrplot producing raised squares in plot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm getting corrplot's with embossed/shadow effect squares:
[image]

If you look carefully, the colored squares almost look 3D, as if they had raised edges. I couldn't find anything that would cause this in the documentation. Is it a platform issue? I want to have completely flat squares.

Here's the code I used:

```
corrplot(abs(cor_matrix), method="color", 
col= colorRampPalette(c("blue", "blue","blue", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))(100) ,
tl.pos="n", cl.lim = c(0,1), order = "hclust")
```

Comment: try a different color palette maybe?

Comment: Also try saving without anti-aliasing

Comment: Turning off anti-aliasing fixes the issue when using png(...) command but doesn't do anything for pdf(...) or cairo_pdf(...)